# White Screen between fragment transactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

Everything is working fine with following code.

```
fragmentManager =   NavigationDrawerActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        ft              =   fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment, fragment_tag);
        ft.commit();
```

When I add the following line:-

```
ft.addToBackStack(fragment_tag);
```

as the second last line, it shows up a white screen when I click back between the fragments.

Comment: all fragments or just the first fragment?

Comment: @YassineBELDI for which ever fragment the above code is invoked.

Comment: well, where else  you used `fragment_tag` in your code?

Comment: You can assume that I do it only here,but I call this same code multiple times.